# What is the error in this disproof of the $\Omega$-conjecture?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, peer-review

I was reading about the $\Omega$-conjecture and have thought of a refutation of it, which seems too simple to not have been noticed since the $\Omega$-conjecture has been around, so i'm skeptical and want to see whether anyone can spot a flaw in it.

I will assume there is a proper class of hyper-huge cardinals. This assumption implies a proper class of Woodin cardinals and by Usuba implies the existence of the bedrock model $W$, and since $V$ is a set-generic extension of $W$ and our assumption (as well as the $\Omega$-conjecture) is invariant throughout the set-generic multiverse, we can work in $W$. Suppose for a contradiction that the $\Omega$-conjecture holds. Since $V = W$ is $\Sigma_2$ definable in any set-forcing $V[G]$, we can uniformly evaluate $\Sigma_2$-truths of $V$ in any set-forcing of $V$ by other recursively given $\Sigma_2$ sentences. Since the $\Sigma_2$-laws of the set-generic multiverse are definable in $H(\delta_0^+)$ where $\delta_0$ is the least Woodin cardinal (by the $\Omega$-conjecture), and they can be used to compute all the $\Sigma_2$ truths of $V$ (including the theory of $H(I_0^{+})$ and beyond), this violates Tarski's undefinability of truth. Thus the $\Omega$-conjecture must fail assuming our large cardinal hypothesis. $\square$

Is this argument really valid? (I'm worried 2016 will end by refuting $V = \text{Ultimate }L$)

Comment: @Stefan Usuba proved that if there is a hyper huge cardinal, then there are only set many grounds (fewer than the least hyper huge), whose intersection is a ground. (And as a matter of terminology, the word "bedrock" means "minimal ground".)

Comment: @Joel Yes, right after posting my comment, I remembered this result by Usuba.

Comment: Uncountable_turtle, could you clarify how you are violating Tarski? After all, there is no problem with having a $\Sigma_2$ truth predicate of $V$--this doesn't violate Tarski. Also, could you clarify the role of parameters when you refer to "$\Sigma_2$-truths".

Comment: I don't allow parameters, and the problem is that i have defined the $\Sigma_2$ truths of $V$ within the small fragment $H(\delta_0^+)$, which is simpler than $\Sigma_2$ truths of all of $V$, since the first $\delta_0$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable.

Comment: Could someone please remind me the definition of *hyper huge* cardinal?

Comment: Also, why do you *worry* that the year will end with a refutation of $V=\text{Ultimate }L$? That's a good thing, not a bad thing! :)

Comment: A cardinal $\kappa$ is hyper huge, if for every $\lambda$ there is $j:V\to M$ with critical point $\kappa$, $j(\kappa)>\lambda$ and $M^{j(\lambda)}\subset M$. This is between super $1$-huge and super $2$-huge. You can see the slides for my talk at the Harvard Logic Colloquium: http://jdh.hamkins.org/recent-advances-in-set-theoretic-geology-harvard-logic-colloquium-october-2016/.

Comment: I still don't understand how Tarski is violated. If $\delta$ is $\Sigma_2$ reflecting, then $V_\delta$ has exactly the same $\Sigma_2$ true assertions as $V$, and these are definable in $V_\delta$.

Comment: Since $\delta_0$ is the least Woodin cardinal, there are no Woodin cardinals in $V_{\delta_0}$, but there are in $V$, so they disagree on the $\Sigma_2$ sentence stating that there is a Woodin cardinal.

Comment: But you evaluate the truth of $\Sigma_2$ statements in $H(\delta_0^+)$ and in there, $\delta_0$ is still Woodin.

Comment: @Stefan True, but $H(\delta_0^+)$ would not see that there are 2 Woodin cardinals.

Comment: $H(\delta^+)$ is never $\Sigma_2$ elementary in $V$, since it doesn't think $V_{\delta+1}$ exists.

Comment: Another issue is that ground models are $\Pi_2$ definable, not $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I don't think it's claimed that $H(\delta^+)$ is elementary, but rather that in it we can define the $\Sigma_2$ truth predicate.

Comment: I think I am mainly confused by the vagueness of OP's post in several instances. Maybe it is possible to fill in some of those gaps? E.g. how and where exactly do we compute $\Sigma_2$ truths and how would that lead to a truth predicate for $V$?

Comment: Yes, the argument is in need of further explanation and clarification. @uncountable_turtle, could you kindly expand on your proposed argument, with about two or three times as much detail and greater precision in the statements you are claiming?

Comment: We are in the bedrock model (so the ground axiom holds) and we compute the $\Sigma_2$ truth predicate by asking the set-generics extensions of $V$ which $\Sigma_2$ sentences are true in our universe $V$, they know that since our unverse $V = W$ is definable (as the bedrock model) and they will all agree the $\Sigma_2$ truths of $W$ but by the definability in $H(\delta_0^+)$ of the set-generic-multiverse laws we the contradiction that $\Sigma_2$-truth is definable in $H(\delta_0^+)$, but then we have a $\Delta_2$ definition of $\Sigma_2$ truth (and even more in higher rank-initial segments).

Comment: OK, that is a little more clear. You are using the fact that $\delta_0$ and hence $H(\delta_0^+)$ is $\Delta_2$ definable itself and then running the generic-multiverse Truth definition there to get a $\Delta_2$-definition in $V$ of the $\Sigma_2$ theory of $V$, which is what you meant by violating Tarski. Right? Can you give a reference for the claim about the $\Sigma_2$ set-generic multiverse laws being definable in $H(\delta_0^+)$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks to verify a proof / disproof.

Comment: @StefanKohl Please don't close the question; it is a fine question, and definitely on topic! I for one would like to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @Joel, you can add a preliminary answer, and then edit it after the question is closed.  Also, many might be dissuaded from closing if they see a post from you with your take on the question.  Gerhard "That Would Be More Visible" Paseman, 2016.12.31.

Comment: I also do nt understand why it contradicts Tarski's theorem, as you are talking just about $\Sigma_2$-sentences. See also [Outer model satisfiability](http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~stanley/talks/logic_colloquium_2008.pdf) and [Definability of satisfaction in outer models](http://logika.ff.cuni.cz/radek/papers/Friedman_Honzik_OuterModels_finalJSL.pdf).

Comment: @MohammadGolshani There is a $\Sigma_2$ predicate in $V$ which defines the set of all statements (including those of complexity higher than $\Sigma_2$) holding in $H(\delta_0^+)$, so if the set of $\Sigma_2$-truths of $V$ was definable in $H(\delta_0^+)$, $H(\delta_0^+)$ could define it's own truth predicate and therefore contradict Tarski's theorem by taking the set of true-in-$V$ sentences of the form "$H(\delta_0^+)$ satisfies $\phi$" (still allowing sentences of arbitrarily high complexity), which are all $\Sigma_2$-evaluatable in $V$ since $H(\delta_0^+)$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable in $V$.

Comment: @uncountable_turtle Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: When you say $V=W$ is $\Sigma_2$-definable in any set forcing extension $V[G]$, don't you need a parameter $a$ to define it. I think you need, i.e., $V=W$ is $\Sigma_2(a)$-definable in $V[G]$, for some parameter $a$, and this parameter varies when we go to different extensions. If so, then maybe going to different extensions, you require different parameters, and so it is not possible to unify them.

Comment: In a set-generic extension $V[G]$, i define our universe $V$ as the bedrock model $W$ ($V = W$ since i'm assuming the ground axiom holds in $V$). All set-generic extensions of $V$ agree on the bedrock (and that it is our universe), the definition of the bedrock is uniform and does not use parameters, and the existence of the bedrock is unchanged by set-forcing. Without the ground axiom in $V$, however, $V$ may need parameters to be defined in set-forcing extensions of the universe.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but there are essentially the same discussions in Woodin's paper [The Continuum Hypothesis, the generic-multiverse of sets, and the Ω Conjecture](http://www.logic.harvard.edu/EFI_Woodin_TheContinuumHypothesis.pdf). See section 5 of the paper "The complexity of the $\Omega$-logic".

Comment: @MohammadGolshani You are right, that is where i found some of the theorems i used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51036/discussion-between-uncountable-turtle-and-mohammad-golshani).

Comment: @StefanKohl I know that you already retracted your close vote, so no harm no foul, but the usual application of "we don't vet proofs here" is to crackpot posts, which doesn't apply here. This seems like a pretty serious and high-level discussion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I know that this comment section is old, but may I please ask You why You would like the refutation of V = Ultimate L and think it would be a good thing?

Comment: @PanMrož: In Woodin's approach, $V=\text{Ultimate }L$ signifies "order" that large cardinals bring to the universe of sets; whereas post-choice axioms such as Reinhardt cardinals, signify chaos, because they imply that there is no "canonical structure" to the universe of set theory. But look all around you, there's no order to the universe. Everything is chaos. Chaos is good. Chaos is your friend. So for my money, I'd rather have the conjecture fail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Woodin's theorem says that assuming the $\Omega$ Conjecture and the existence of a proper class of Woodin cardinals, the set $\mathcal V_\Omega$ of $\Pi_2$ sentences that hold in every universe of the generic multiverse is lightface definable over $H_{\delta^+}$ where $\delta$ is the least Woodin cardinal. You claim there is a Turing reduction from the $\Pi_2$ theory of the bedrock to $\mathcal V_\Omega$, obtaining in this way a $\Sigma_2$ definition of $\Pi_2$ truth (assuming the Ground Axiom), a contradiction. The proposed reduction sends a formula $\phi$ to the sentence $f(\phi)$ expressing "The bedrock satisfies $\phi$." Tell me if I'm misunderstanding you.

One problem: it isn't clear that $f(\phi)$ is $\Pi_2$. Note that if $W$ is a $\Sigma_2$ or $\Pi_2$ or even $\Delta_2$ inner model and $\phi$ is a $\Pi_2$ sentence, the sentence $W\vDash \phi$ is not obviously $\Pi_2$. We can write $\phi$ as $$\forall x \ (x\notin W \vee \exists y\ (y\in W\wedge \psi(x,y))$$ for some $\Delta_0$ formula $\psi$. This seems to be no simpler than $\Pi_3$ even if $W$ is  $\Delta_2$.

For example, we claim that the statement $$\Psi\equiv \text{CH}\text{ fails in the bedrock}$$ is not equivalent over ZFC + the Bedrock Axiom to a $\Pi_2$ formula, even though $\neg\text{CH}$ is $\Delta_2$. (The Bedrock Axiom just asserts that the generic multiverse has a bedrock.) Suppose towards a contradiction that this statement *is* equivalent to a $\Pi_2$ formula, which we may assume is of the form $\forall \alpha\  (V_\alpha\vDash \psi)$. Fix a model $$M\vDash\text{the Bedrock Axiom}+\neg\text{CH} + \neg\Psi$$ (so the bedrock of the generic multiverse of $M$ satisfies $\text{CH}$). Since $M\vDash \neg \Psi$, there is some ordinal $\alpha$ of $M$ such that $M_\alpha\vDash \neg \psi$. Now pass to a class forcing extension $M[H]$ satisfying the Ground Axiom and such that $M[H]_{\alpha} = M_{\alpha}$ and $M[H]_{\omega+\omega} = M_{\omega+\omega}$. (See Reitz's thesis, Theorem 12.) We have $M[H]\vDash \neg\text{CH}$ (since $M\vDash \neg \text{CH}$ and $M[H]_{\omega+\omega} = M_{\omega+\omega}$). On the other hand since $M[H]_\alpha = M_\alpha\vDash \neg \psi$, $M[H]\vDash \exists \alpha\ (V_\alpha\vDash \neg \psi)$. Thus $M[H]\vDash \neg \Psi,$ so the bedrock of $M[H]$ satisfies $\text{CH}$, which contradicts the fact that $M[H]$ is its own bedrock.